# Downloading a CSV file using read.xls in r

Tags: r, rcurl

I'm trying to import a CSV file from this URL, but this simple line of code doesn't work on this URL.

```
read.csv("https://www.cboe.com/publish/vxthdata/vxth_dailydata.xls")
```

I tried getURL from RCurl library, faced the same issue.

Comment: The file ends with "xls" which usually means an Excel file, not a CSV file. Those are very different file formats.

Comment: Searching for "how to import Excel file into R" will give you lots of things to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrFlick says, your file is an Excel file, not a CSV file. 
You can use `readxl` and `curl`.

```
url <- "https://www.cboe.com/publish/vxthdata/vxth_dailydata.xls"
destfile <- "vxth_dailydata.xls"
curl::curl_download(url, destfile)
vxth_dailydata <- readxl::read_excel(destfile, col_types = c("date", rep("numeric", 9)))
file.remove(destfile)
rm(url, destfile)
View(vxth_dailydata)
```

Regards!!

Answer (score 1):

Right! just overlooked it...

```
library(gdata)
read.xls("https://www.cboe.com/publish/vxthdata/vxth_dailydata.xls")
```